# asp.net mvc using HREF in application running on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There is a partial view representing pager control (very similar to [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/02/21/simple-pager-for-asp-net-mvc.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)) for blog content. Code generates HTML with  references and href like, `"/Blog/Posts/Page/1"`, `"/Blog/Posts/Page/2"` etc.

It worked absolutely fine on Cassini, but after I switched to IIS problems appeared.

IIS application running in virtual folder, so URL is

```
http://localhost/tracky
```

and blog area located,

```
http://localhost/tracky/blog
```

As I press on pager button, I recieve 404, because the URL would be

```
http://localhost/blog/page/3
```

Instead of

```
http://localhost/tracky/blog/page/3
```

My question is, how to handle such situation? how to change code generation to provide correct URL? how to make it work same - as root applicaton or application in virtual folder?

Source code is [here](http://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/Trackyourtasks.net/blob/master/src/Web/Helpers/Extensions/PagerBuilder.cs)

Comment: how are you generating the url?

Comment: now it is just hardcoded as "/Blog/Posts/Page" + pageIndex;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to generate your urls either by using `ActionLink` in your view, or using an UrlHelper in your href as follows: `<a href="<%=Url.Content("~/blog/page/3")%>" ..>bla</a>`. This will generate Urls that are adjusted accoring to your application root.

Comment: how is it possible to use it from code-behind, HtmlExtension helper class ? I could not find Url namespace

Comment: ActionLink variant works for me... <%: Html.Pager(Url.Action("Page", "Posts", new { area = "Blog", id="{0}"}), Model.TotalPages, Model.CurrentPage)%>

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the following:

```
UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl("~/Blog/Posts/Page/1");
```

The `~` allows the url to be resolved relative to the application path and should produce correct results in both cassini and IIS.

Comment: I think `Content` instead of `GenerateContentUrl` will suffice. There's no need to fully qualify the urls.

Comment: UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl also recieves httpContext, that make it difficult to use code in helper classes.. and unit test it.